# Intelli j 14.1 settings freeze for the first 2 minutes since it was open

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

Every time I try to change my settings, I encounter this problem. 
Also when I do some changes or switch tabs in the settings dialog. 
Can someone Help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide additional information such us:
1. java version
2. OS version (61/32 bits)
3. IntelliJ Idea version - including the build number. Copy the information offered by About

I came across similar issue and the root cause was in the incorrect executable intellij idea installer used to create Windows shortcut.
For my case even if the OS was Windows 7 64 bit the executable used was 32 bit. 
I modified the executable used by the shortcut to be the idea64, and the issues with frequent IDE freezes gone.

I hope this will help.

Kr

Comment: Java version -  7 update 79. Os version - 64 bits. IIntelli j Idea version  - 14.1.4 .  build number - IU-141.1532.4. about: jre: 1.7.0_79-b15 amd64. built on june 18, 2015. My windows shortcut is indeed idea64, so do you have any other suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, Iior. Unfortunately nothing else reliable crops in my head. I would look in the log file - Help->Show log.

Comment: Thanks anyway!  I have new information that would might help: the freeze actualy happens each time I try to enter the "Keymap" tab.(this is also the default marked tab, and that's why I thought the whole settings menu froze).

Comment: Hi Iior. This sounds like an issue. You can fill it in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.